# Good piece of software that can manage the creation of complex web forms, including reporting, etc?

Tags: forms, reporting

I have some clients who are requesting for some of their reasonably complex paper-based forms to be converted in to web forms. There's straight Q&A text input stuff, there's questions based around checkboxes, radio boxes, select boxes, maybe the occasional attached image, there's data that has to be entered in a tabular fashion, etc.

I am deciding whether I should build a "platform" with properly normalised tables to store all types of form data. But before that, I thought I had better check and see if there is anything like that already on the market.

I am looking for a product that can:
* Easily create web forms of all types
* Store all data in a database
* Extensive reporting capability

I have had a bit of a look around but there's not a whole lot I can see. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Formstack](http://www.formstack.com/) has been around for a while as an online forms product, as has [Surveymonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/). Both are SaaS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of **writing your own SurveyEngine** like SurveyMonkey for your client.